# Collection deny rule property undefined

Tags: meteor

When invoking this in the browser console:
`Meteor.users.update({_id:'2MA7iPq7bNtfxGm6r'},{$unset:{'profile.taskInProgress':''}})`

This Meteor server code is giving this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile.taskInProgress' of undefined

```
Meteor.users.deny({
  update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    const tasks = ['search', 'aSearch'];
    return (!(
      userId &&
      userId == Meteor.userId() &&
      (tasks.indexOf(modifier.$set['profile.taskInProgress']) >= 0) || //<--comment for next line to work
      (modifier.$unset['profile.taskInProgress'] == '') // <-- or comment for the above line to work
    ));
  }
});
```

it works if I comment out the "error line", but if I do that then I will loose the permission to $set it. So now it appears like I can have one or the other but not both permissions. Must be some problem with my code.

How to allow the client to unset the 'profile.taskInProgress' property?

Comment: Does `taskInProgress` exist in `profile`?

Comment: It sure does. And it works if I comment out the "error line", but if I do that then I will loose the permission to `$set` it. So now it appears like I can have one or the other but not both. Must be some problem with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have a logic problem.

your expression is basically this:

```
!(a && b && c || d)
```

c is valid only when you're doing a $set, and d is valid only when you're doing an $unset.

if your expression were this (without the prefixing bang):

```
(a && b && c || d)
```

... then, for a $set, the evaluation will be: a, b, c. if those are all true, then the condition is satisfied. it does not need to proceed to evaluation of d. that's good, because i think that would fail due to lack of null check.

but if $unset is used, then i believe that c will fail, because of a lack of null check. (i'm not positive here, but i think that's what's going on).

but, you have the entire expression "notted". that's going to force evaulation of each of a, b, c, and d, regardless of whether $set or $unset is being used. and this will always fail due to lack of null checks.

what you really mean, i think, is:

```
!(a && b && (c || d))
```

as written, you could *not* have a userId, and as long as d is true (and null checks were in place), you would allow the operation.

to solve it, i would break out the evaulation from the overall logic. e.g.

```
let userIdExists = !!userId;
let requesterIsLoggedInUser = (userId === Meteor.userId());
let progressSet = (modifier.$set && (tasks.indexOf(modifier.$set['profile.taskInProgress']) >= 0));
let progressUnset = (modifier.$unset && (modifier.$unset['profile.taskInProgress'] == ''));

let allowed = userIdExists && requesterIsLoggedInUser && (progressSet || progressUnset);

let denied = !allowed;

return denied;
```

i tend to be verbose in logic situations like this, to ensure each condition is easily understood.

btw, why is this not expressed as an allow rule? returning "allow" instead of "!allowed" in a deny seems easier to read, imho.

edit: the allow version simply does a "return allowed;" at the end, instead of bothering with the denied variable.

if you're trying to debug, console.log() out all the vars to see if they're what you expect. if you want, update your question w/ those results and console logs of modifier so it's easier to confirm the logic for progressSet and progressUnset.

Comment: I tried your code as posted but it failed to allow access. Browser says Access denied. Could you please show the allowed version, I agree it is easier to read.

Comment: check answer for edit. i'm unsure why it's not working, so some console.log()'s will help debug.